# np.astype not changing array type

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, netcdf

I have a many datasets I'm ingesting that include latitude and longitude values. One of these has their lat and lon fields set to float64 whilst everyone else is using float32. So, I'm initially trying to simply convert the type - except the type conversion doesn't appear to be happening.

To make things worse I'm not receiving any error messages, so it''s a little hard to troubleshoot.

Is there some obvious error I have here? The lat_ref should exist in an array, initially as a Float64. I'd like to replace that array with one whose values are Float32 and I don't mind if the values are truncated to match float32 since a latitude with a float64 would be measured in nanometers.

Example code:

```
lat_ref = nc.variables['lat'][:] #This is where I read in the lat from my data
lat_ref = lat_ref.astype(np.float32)

print("The shape of lat_ref is: " + str(np.shape(lat_ref)))
print("The dtype of lat_ref is: " + str(lat_ref.dtype))
```

The result of the print is:

```
The shape of lat_ref is: (681,)
The dtype of lat_ref is: float64
```

My other datasets respond to the print (without the .astype transform) like so:

```
The shape of lat_ref is: (408,)
The dtype of lat_ref is: float32
```

I would like the transform to cause the lat_ref to be like the above.

Comment: `astype` does not operate in-place.  It returns a new array.

Comment: So I should create a new array, drop the old array and rename the new array?

Comment: Sorry, I see you do assign the result to `lat_ref`.  So I would expect it to work.  But, does the `nc.` suggest you are loading this from something lie `NETCDF`.  I wonder if `lat_ref` as loaded is really  a `np.ndarray`.  I haven't used `NETCDF`.

Comment: I am indeed loading from NetCDF files. I'm actually trying to back trace an entirely separate error that I think is being caused by incorrect data types. I did get the type conversion working in the end. I'm using double the memory space, but the issue went away. ``` lat_ref64 = nc.variables['lat'][:]
        lat_ref = lat_ref64.astype(np.float32) ```.
I actually think the error might be because the NetCDF variable is referencing a float64 dimension and it therefore wont matter how much I try to coerce it, I actually need to handle the netcdf first and perform a transform.

Comment: `print(type(lat_ref))` and show us what you get. This doesn't look like a NumPy array.

Comment: For anyone reading this in the future - I was unable to resolve this error and instead had to use a different starting filetype the convert over in a manner where I could inspect and modify the data. A combination of GDAL and xarray was needed for that approach. I suspect the files I was being supplied had dud data in them somewhere.